# Disable input field if it has contents via ID or class

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have an account field that I don't want the use to be able to change once they have submitted it.

So when they bring up their profile the field is disabled, but they can see the content.

This is in Wordpress with WooCommerce form. Following is generated in the HTML.

```
<p class="form-row form-row form-row-wide" id="billing_givingnumber_field">
    <label for="billing_givingnumber" class="">Giving Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_givingnumber" id="billing_givingnumber" placeholder="Giving Number" value="123456" display="text">
</p>
```

Can I change this with a simple if else statement in either PHP or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Set the element's `disabled` property to true:

```
var x = document.getElementById("billing_givingnumber").value;
if(x != "") {
     document.getElementById("billing_givingnumber").disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Output number as string instead of input field value, if it is already submitted with simple php if loop. You can add disabled flag to input field, but that can be edited through inspector.

```
<input type="text" name="name" disabled>
```